# Training model on TPU VM aborts with core dump

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, nlp, virtual-machine, tpu

I am trying to train T5X on the Winograd schema challenge. When I run my training script, I receive the following error.

```
2022-08-21 17:27:01.141608: F ./tensorflow/core/tpu/tpu_library_init_fns.inc:101] TpuEmbeddingEngine_ConfigureCommunication not available in this library.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any idea of what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We faced this issue yesterday as well, what fixed it for us was setting the TPU software version as `tpu-vm-base` when provisioning the TPU node.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my issue which I had been debugging for several days. Marking as the correct answer.